# pdfcrop not found after Ubuntu update

Tags: package-management, updates, 19.10, update-manager, pdf

I had `pdfcrop` installed on Ubuntu 19.04 and it worked fine. However, after updating it to 19.10, I could not use it anymore. It returns me the following error:

```
pdfcrop: command not found
```

If I try to install it from the old source, I have the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-extra-utils

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package texlive-extra-utils is not available, but is referred to by 
another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
texlive-base
```

When installing `texlive-base` the error continues.

Here is what I get when running `apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease Hit:2
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                       
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease              
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97,5
kB]      Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security
InRelease [97,5 kB] Fetched 195 kB in 1s (256 kB/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
```

Is there any other path I should add to successfully install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks like this:

```
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

I do not have issues with `sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils` command on 19.10.

[source.list](https://gist.github.com/malikalichsan/860b8134a74c65a394efe09711d0b95f)